# which function is used, template or not?

Tags: c++, function

I have declared two functions:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T& in) { cout << in; }
void foo(bool& b) { cout << "Bool:" << (b ? "True" : "False");}
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
bool var = false; foo(var);
```

I know I can write test code. But if this is a compiler dependent choice,
writing test code will never have full coverage.

Comment: I mean invoke by: bool var = false; foo(var);

Comment: If it is a compiler dependent choice how can you expect to get a single answer?

Comment: It isn’t compiler dependent (unless a compiler is in error). If a template and a nin-template are equally good matches, the non-template is preferred. BTW you can get `bool` formatted as a string using `out << std::boolalpha << true;` (the flag applies until it is reset). By default that would format as `true` (or `false`). If really necessary the string can be changed by using a custom `std::numpunct<char>` facet.

Answer (score 2):

The second one, i.e.:

```
void foo(bool& b) { cout << "Bool:" << (b ? "True" : "False");}
```

since it will be a better match for `bool var = false; foo(var);`.

In general, overload resolutions favor non-templated methods over templated ones, as you can read in the [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution):

> **Best viable function**
>
> F1 is determined to be a better function than F2
>   if implicit conversions [..]:
>
> F1 is a non-template function while F2 is a template specialization

---

PS: This is *not* compiler-dependent, as there are rules that describe how the overload resolution occurs in such cases, as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Overload resolution usually prefers non-template functions over template functions. So the `bool&` version will be called. This is well-defined, not up to the compiler to decide.

For details, see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), the section "Best viable function". (I could try linking to the Standard, but presumably it's even harder to read.)